# Facebook Graph API - Javascript SDK

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

How can I post to a user's wall using Javascript SDK?

Comment: Do you want to show the "post to wall" dialog? I need a little more info.

Comment: yes i want to show a post to wall dialog. you can check my app at http://apps.facebook.com/mystatusinhindi/

Comment: in the app i want to post the user generated status using a button on the page.

Comment: possible duplicate of [post message to facebook from <textarea> using fb.ui?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5305745/post-message-to-facebook-from-textarea-using-fb-ui)

Comment: This is exactly what you are asking for, please use the search next time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Facebook strongly advises against directly posting to user's feed without direct consent of each specific post, you should really try using the javascript SDK's FB.ui functionality:

```
    function PostToWall(msg) {

         FB.ui(
           {
         method: 'feed',
         name: 'I'm using this great app and it says that '"+msg"'",
         link: 'http://apps.facebook.com/link-to-app,
         picture: 'http://yourdomain.com/images/facebook-logo.png',
         caption: 'Small caption that will appear in grey'
           }

         );

    }
```

Read more about it [here](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.ui/)