# Is Prefilled message deprecated on feed dialog for sharing from July12?

Tags: facebook, dialog, feed, sharing

I have just implemented the feed dialog in my app for sharing activities on facebook. My requirement is to have some prefilled message on the feed dialog while sharing. But is prefilled messages on feed dialog really now been deprecated by Facebook from July 12. Please confirm the news and suggest a solution how to go for "prefilled message".

Comment: Then, Please suggest me another way to do it. I want to have the prefilled message feed dialog on a ruby on rails web application sharing various activities.

Comment: There is no way of doing that.

Comment: Pre-filling the message box is agains Facebook policy. Instead, us the caption or description fields to add your message.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Please confirm the news and suggest a solution how to go for "prefilled message".

“News”? Lol.

You can only do that, if you do not use the feed dialog, but post using the API.

But [Platform Policies](https://developers.facebook.com/policy/) say you must not post any text that has not been entered by the user themselves beforehand (*IV. Application Integration Points, 2.*).

Giving them a pre-filled text box where they can edit the given message before submitting it to your app would be a gray area. But you should also keep in mind that if lots of users submit the same, unaltered message and you post it to their timeline on their behalf, Facebook’s algorithms will most likely detect that very easily – and therefor distribution of your posts might be limited.