# Facebook login, Notification to users feed

Tags: java, php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-apps

I have incorporated a facebook login using javascript into my forum. To add a bit of value, I want when someone signs up to the forum using their facebook account, it will send a notification to the users feed in which their connections will be able to see. For example:

> user3743982 just signed up for Service X. The best X Service about.

Does anybody have any good resources they could share on how to do this? I have since this done hundreds of times, but have failed in my hunt for material, tutorials, and know hows.

Thanks in advance

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2724977/using-facebook-graph-to-simply-post-a-wall-message-with-just-javascript

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this by calling [FB.api](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/javascript/reference/FB.api) method once you get the response object after authentication. Note that you need to get `publish_actions` permission in order to make publishing API calls. So, your final code must look something like:

```
FB.login(function(response) {
   if (response.authResponse) {
     FB.api('/me/feed', 'post', {message: 'I signed up for the service X!'});
     });
   } else {
     console.log('User cancelled login or did not fully authorize.');
   }
 }, {scope: 'publish_actions'});
```

You can find more information on this in the following documents:

- [FB.login Permissions](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.login/#permissions)
- [Using Javascript SDK to call Graph API](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/javascript/quickstart#graphapi).