# Asp.net and facebook share buttom

Tags: asp.net, facebook-share

i have an asp.net web application and i need to add a button that shares content to facebook.
Is there any way to do it ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using Facebook Graph to simply post a wall message with just javascript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2724977/using-facebook-graph-to-simply-post-a-wall-message-with-just-javascript)

Answer (score 0):

You can share your webpage on Facebook by referring to the developer guide provided by facebook.

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/reference/share-dialog